# How to get Header / Footer parts from Excel Document

Tags: excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to get the header / footer parts from an excel document so that I can do something with their contents, however I cannot seem to get anything from them.

I thought this would be pretty simple... Consider this code:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true))
{
    var headers = spreadsheet.GetPartsOfType<HeaderPart>().ToList();

    foreach (var header in headers)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Even with a file that contains a header, headers will always be empty. I've tried drilling down into the `workbook -> worksheets -> etc` but i get nothing back. My testing excel file definitely has a header (headers are ghastly in excel!).

Annoyingly the api's for excel in openxml seem to be worse as in a docx you can get the header by calling:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, true))
{
    MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;

    var headerParts = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts.ToList();

    foreach (var headerPart in headerParts)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I've seen some people on google saying that I should query the worksheet's descendants (code from [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e1fd08d9-2816-4ab9-9e4e-8370d0b67c60/how-to-read-excelxlsx-file-headerfooter-by-using-open-xml-in-c?forum=oxmlsdk)):

```
HeaderFooter hf = ws.Descendants<HeaderFooter>().FirstOrDefault();
if (hf != null)
{
//here you can add your code
//I just try to append here for demo
  hf = new HeaderFooter();
  ws.AppendChild<HeaderFooter>(hf);
}
```

But I cannot see any way of querying the workbook/sheet/anything with `.Descendants` and obviously none of the code examples on google show how they got `ws` .

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: In VBA headers must be accessed via `LeftHeader`, `CenterHeader` and `RightHeader` and footers via `LeftFooter`, `CenterFooter` and `RightFooter`, perhaps you need something similar?

Answer (score 1):

`HeaderFooter`, as per your second example, is the correct way to read a Header or Footer from a Spreadsheet using OpenXML. The `ws` in your example refers to a `Worksheet`.

The following is an example that reads the `HeaderFooter` and dumps the `InnerText` to the console.

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, false))
{
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
    Worksheet ws = worksheetPart.Worksheet;

    HeaderFooter hf = ws.Descendants<HeaderFooter>().FirstOrDefault();

    if (hf != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(hf.InnerText);
    }
}
```

I would highly recommend that you read the documentation for the `HeaderFooter` element as it's more complex than you might imagine. The documentation can be found in section 18.3.1.46 of the Fifth Edition of the Ecma Office Open XML Part 1 - Fundamentals And Markup Language Reference which can be found [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm).

Comment: I had actually tried `ws.Descendants<HeaderFooter>().FirstOrDefault();` before posting this question but it returns null. I was able to grab it by doing `ws.ChildElements.Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(HeaderFooter))`.I agree it's complicated, i've been able to read the header / footer and read / replace the values. Getting there was a horrendous process and I'm half tempted to write a wrapper library so other people don't have to suffer using open xml....